# Flutter: Why I get overexposed photo on Android?

Tags: flutter

I want my app to take photos with flash. And there is a problem with exposure on Android.

To do this im using `package:camera/camera.dart`.
Here are the methods I am using to take a photo:

```
await _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);
var photo = await _controller.takePicture()
```

At iOS everything works fine.
But on Android I get the following:

[image]

On the left - image that I receive in my app.
On the right - image of the same object from the same angle made by native android camera app. with flash

The question is - how can I fix this and get the same photo image in my app as I receive in native camera app?

Comment: I would suggest you to use this package `image_picker: ^0.8.5`, works perfect